# Disable spinner previous `OnItemSelected` call

Tags: android, spinner

I have a `ViewPager` with 10 "pages" and in one of the "pages" (page 9) I have some `spinners`.

When I'm on the page of the `spinners` I have a flag so that `onItemSelected´ doesn't get fired in the initial spinner setup.

I then use some of the `spinners` and chose some options (in one `spinners` I select the second option and on another I select the third option). They work as expected. I then navigate, for example, to page 1. Now, when I go back to the page that I have the `spinners`, `onCreateView` gets called again and I setup the spinners again:

```
firstSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.myfirstspinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.background,
                new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.firstSpinnerOptions))));

myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinnerlayout);
firstSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
firstSpinner.setSelection(0);
```

I do this for all spinners.

Once again, I set the flag so that `onItemSelected´ doesn't get fired for the initial setup.

The problem is, as I said before, I've selected some options the first time I was on the page. Now, `onItemSelected´ is called with the previous options and the spinners`firstSpinner.setSelection(0);` is overridden by the previous selected option.

How can I disable the previous calls?

Answer (score 0):

try running you function in onResume.
when you swipe layouts the oncreate doesn't always run.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
// your function
}
```

Comment: Its the same situation